# What does the phrase "on to" mean?

Tags: american-english

The following sentence is the context.

> Accordingly, in the next few chapters, which deal specifically with the tags, we’ll spend a lot more time on the OGNL expression language. On to chapter 6!

Your answers or comments are appreciated!

Comment: The two answers below, in tandem, cover this well. 

I'm on to you!

Comment: @Neil: But only in the context the questioner asked it in, not necessarily the context your comment uses it in (great example by the way). In that situation it means "I know what you are doing/saying/planning/implying."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It means, roughly, "proceed to", but has more of a tone of encouragement or excitement rather than a command. You can think of it as having an implicit "Let's move" at the beginning, as in "(Let's move) on to chapter 6!"

Answer (score 1):

This is generally used  as an mild enthusiastic exclamation.

It is implied that some subject is moving on to whatever is described.  In this case, "Here we go, we are moving on to chapter 6!" is equivalent.